# JMS session thread implications

Tags: java, multithreading, jms

What does it mean that :

> A Session object is a single-threaded context for producing and consuming messages

Why does `Session` extends `Runnable`?
Does that imply that when we create a new session object, a new application level thread is always started?

Please I need help on understanding this.

Comment: I don't think it's implied.  Pretty sure it's saying that explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does that imply that when we create a new session object, a new application level thread is always started?

No, it implies that when *you* start a new thread you should acquire a new `Session` for it. It says that right in the [same place you were looking](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/Session.html):

> If a client desires to have one thread produce messages while others consume them, the client should use a separate session for its producing thread.
>
> Once a connection has been started, any session with one or more registered message listeners is dedicated to the thread of control that delivers messages to it. It is erroneous for client code to use this session or any of its constituent objects from another thread of control. The only exception to this rule is the use of the session or connection close method.